# How can i proxy a mediastream object without TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, proxy, javascript-objects, media-player, mediastream

I recently was trying to proxy a MediaStream Object in javascript And noticed i could but there was an error. I used the following code.

```
function createChangeableStream(stream) {
                    stream["_stream_"]=stream;
                        return new Proxy(stream,{
                    set: function(obj, prop, value){
                          if(prop==="_stream_")
                             obj._stream_=value;
                          else
                             obj._stream_[prop]=value;
                    },
                    get: function(obj, prop) {
                         if(prop==="_stream_")
                             return obj._stream_;
                         else
                             return obj._stream_[prop];
                    }
                });
                }
```

since i could not change the target... i used the above workaround.
Each time i try to call `MediaStream.getTracks()`, i get `TypeError: Illegal invocation` I would be grateful for your help. The function works with any other objects. and the 'target' is changed by modifying `_stream_` property. I also realized that this

```js
let x=new Proxy(stream,{});
x.getTracks()
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for anyone with almost similar problem i succeeded evading the error with the following code.

```js
function createChangeableStream(stream) {
                    stream["_stream_"]=stream;
                    stream["_call_handler_"]=function (obj,prop,args) {
                        return obj[prop](...args);
                    }
                        return new Proxy(stream,{
                    set: function(obj, prop, value){
                          if(prop==="_stream_")
                             obj._stream_=value;
                          else
                             obj._stream_[prop]=value;
                    },
                    get: function(obj, prop) {
                         if(prop==="_stream_")
                             return obj._stream_;
                         else if((typeof obj._stream_[prop])==="function"){
                              return function () {
                                 return obj._call_handler_(obj._stream_,prop,[...arguments]);
                              } 
                          }else
                             return obj._stream_[prop];
                    }
                });
                }
```

but i still don't know why the error exists at the first place. maybe its a bug, i don't know.